# Stack trace: PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso on line 31

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema con mi cóigo. ¿Me podrian ayudar a identificar que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("
                SELECT * FROM usuarios 
                WHERE nombre_usuario = :usuario_log 
                AND contraseña = :pass_log
            ");
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '�a =
> 'cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d1...'
> at line 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-php\48.practica\accion\admin\login.php:31 Stack
> trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-php\48.practica\accion\admin\login.php(31):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-php\48.practica\accion\admin\login.php on line
> 31

Comment: Por lo que me parece, tienes un problema de conexión con la base de datos y el encode que estás usando para ello. Si te fijas en el error, diria que se lia cuando intenta interpretar la `ñ` de **contraseña**, y por eso te arroja un error `'�a =` cuando eso deberia ser `ña =`.  Revisa los encodes de tu base de datos y cómo te conectas a ella desde PHP y que coincidan para solucionarlo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias eso mismo era el problema. No debi usar la ñ.

Comment: No estoy tan seguro que no puedas usar la `ñ`, más bien creo que el problema lo tienes en la conexión a ella pues debes estar usando un collation que no es el que espera. Haz una prueba, vuelve a poner la `ñ` y fíjate en la primera respuesta de este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807202/how-to-specify-collation-with-pdo-without-set-names) para establecer la conexión a ella mediante PDO, agregando eso que ponen de `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` tal como lo ponen ellos, y prueba de nuevo. Sino después quizás te salen otros errores con caracteres al guardar.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, sobre eso tambien tenias razon el problema estaba en la conexion a la base de datos. Cree una clase llamada "class Conectar" que deberia ir antes  del metodo conexion.

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas podido arreglar... :-)  eso normalmente pasa porque en el servidor MySQL esta puesta otra collation por defecto (o en la base de datos) y cuando se conecta creo que primero intenta usar la que tenga el servidor, por eso debemos forzarlo en estos casos con el SET NAMES.